# Trying to boot rom

Tags: operating-system, android-source, rom

I have been trying to boot a custom rom build 4 builds done but none of them booted I have pasted the last builds log.

What happens is that it stays at `bootanimation` for some time and then reboots back to recovery. I am using `OrangeFox` Recovery for my device which shows android rescue party trigger.

Full log link is also pasted below.

```
10-11 05:42:27.540 I/init    (    1): type=1400 audit(0.0:3): avc: denied { setcheckreqprot } for scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:kernel:s0 tclass=security permissive=1
10-11 05:42:27.540 I/init    (    1): type=1400 audit(0.0:4): avc: denied { dac_read_search } for capability=2 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1
10-11 05:42:27.543 I/init    (  528): type=1400 audit(0.0:5): avc: denied { map } for path="/plat_file_contexts" dev="rootfs" ino=15240 scontext=u:r:vendor_init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:file_contexts_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
```

https://pastebin.com/4LpY0Xi3

Comment: SELinux denials are not the issue in your case. As you can see you have them on permissive mode ( which means log but dont deny ). The problem is elsewhere. Post the full logcat

Comment: I have posted the pastebin link that's the log i think.(I am newbie into this stuff nd even linux) so i might be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

type=1400 audit(0.0:4): avc: denied { dac_read_search } for capability=2 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1

I'm also a beginner but i can see that you have an emulated drive aka "kworker" preventing you, i also see abc is denied.  It's very possible something or someone may have opened up your cell phone and placed hardware components into it preventing you from adapting to your own mind map of interdemisional understanding.   I definitely need to go back to school For cybersecurity.  .  Hope you figure it out.  I like your idea, just remember the stacks are typically 4 levels down so to stay under it u need at least 5.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't catch what you are trying to explain here maybe because i am a newbie but a little more explanation will help for sure.